# MySQL form upload error - checkbox node ER_BADD_NULL_ERROR: Column ' ' cannot be NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, checkbox, null, forms

I have a form with checkboxes, I want to have data to be uploaded into ***mysql database***.

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="belgie" value="1">België</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="denemarken" value="1">Denemarken</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="duitsland" value="1">Duitsland</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="frankrijk" value="1">Frankrijk</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="italie" value="1">Italië</li>
</ul>
```

During import error is raised.

```
Error: ER_BADD_NULL_ERROR: Column ' ' cannot be NULL
```

The checkboxes that are not checked, are given a value of NULL. 
I want the values of the unchecked boxes to be 0.

I've tried also with input type"hidden" name="belgie" value="0", unfortunately error is being raised, as there are 2 values, 0 and 1. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Not much of a details as to how you are importing form data into database.

If you will add a class to your form than in PHP you can do:

```
$var= (isset($_POST['YOUR_CLASS'])) ? 1 : 0;
```

As to error that you are getting with "hidden" type, please try with setting up different id's for your input:

```
<input id="belgie" type="checkbox" name="belgie" value="1">
<input id="belgieHidden" type="hidden" name="belgie" value="0">
```

*Wanted to add it as a comment, but I doesn't have enough reputation.*